# How many threads will be created for multiple RTopic objects in a jvm?

Tags: redis, publish-subscribe, redisson

If I create multiple RTopic objects using Redisson, for subscribing to multiple channels, how many threads will be created ? for example if I have 2 RTopic objects.

As per the documentation, 16 threads will be created for all listeners for an RTopic object. But what will be the case of multiple RTopics ?

Answer (score 1):

Same 16 threads will handle listeners of all RTopic instances.